# Highcharts points not cleared out in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to draw chart dynamically on mouse over a table row. What i want is to clear out the chart out and hide the chart on mouse out.

I works fine in chrome but i get this strange behavior in firefox : The chart points remains there. I don't know if i'm clear enough. You can see this on http://dev.bluesquare.org/dev/data.

If you mouse over table with the title "National Quantities" you'll see a chart appearing on mouse over and disappearing on mouse out but leaving some dots on the table.

Is there anybody who can give me an idea about this problem.

Here is part of the code i'm using

```
$(function(){

    $('#district-quantity table tbody tr').hover(function(){
          var row_data = //get some data corresponding to the hovered row
          var chartDiv = 'chart_div';   
          drawQuantityChart(row_data,chartDiv);
       },function(){});
  }

  function drawQuantityChart(row_data,chartDiv) {
            //call a function to parse and format the data for highcharts
            var chartData = parseData(row_data);

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart : {
                    renderTo : chartDiv,
                    type : 'line',
                    height : 360
                },
                title : {
                    text : null
                },
                subtitle : {
                    text : null
                },
                xAxis : {

                    categories : chartData.periods
                },
                yAxis : {
                    title : {
                        text : null
                    },
                    gridLineWidth : 1,
                    min: 0
                },
                tooltip: {                        
                    followPointer: true   

                },
                series : chartData.series
            });    
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $('#district-quantity table tbody tr').hover(function(){
              var row_data = //get some data corresponding to the hovered row
              var chartDiv = 'chart_div';   
              drawQuantityChart(row_data,chartDiv);
           },function(){ 
                   chart.destroy();
                  // Why don't you destroy your chart here? Make sure your chart variable is global.
            });
      }
```